# how to get a free search API for meta search engine in C#

Tags: c#, search-engine

I want to write a meta search engine in C# for that I Need search API from 2 search engines,I have already got google's API,I wanted to use Bing API but it seems that they don't support this service anymore.do yo know any other search engines that I could get its search API for free?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You still have the Bing Search API, it has been moved to cognitive services:
https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/bing-web-search-api

Comment: Thanks it worked perfectly!